# How to round and sum up decimals in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my website I have a form like this:

```
<select id="payments" multiple="multiple">
  <option data-amount="23.1" value="1">Invoice 1</option>
  <option data-amount="25.3" value="2">Invoice 2</option>
  <option data-amount="50.0" value="3">Invoice 3</option>
</select>
```

And a little dash of Javascript:

```
$(function() {

    // Sum up and insert open_amount into 'amount' field depending on what invoice numbers are selected
    $("#payments").change(function() {
        var sum = 0;
        $('#payments :selected').each(function() {
            sum += Number($(this).data("amount"));
        });
        $("#payment_amount").val(sum);
    });

});
```

The problem is that I sometimes get weird numbers like `48.400000000000006` where I actually want rounded results with two decimal places.

How can I properly sum up all the selected amounts?

Comment: It's a common issue that float numbers are broken.
Other languages give alternative solutions, such as decimal for c# and java but I found nothing for javascript.

Comment: I'm not sure of the general SO etiquette, but it's seems odd to mark  this as a duplicate of a question that itself has been closed as a duplicate of another!  Perhaps this should point to "[Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.toFixed(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to format the decimal values.

```
 $("#payment_amount").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toFixed(2)` for two decimal points

```
$("#payment_amount").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

use `parseFloat()` to convert it to a float then add it.

```
sum = sum + parseFloat($(this).data("amount"));
```

Then make it to 2 decimal points using `.toFixed(2)`

```
$("#payment_amount").val(sum.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: The OP is already using the `Number()` constructor which has the advantage of returning 0 for empty entries instead of `NaN`.

Comment: Thank you for the "parseFloat()". I forgot these.

Answer (score 0):

it may be crazy but it will work:

```
parseFloat(48.400000000000006.toLocaleString())
```